# Redirect if User's IP Address is in .txt file

Tags: php, if-statement

I have tried `REMOTE_ADDR` and also `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` but im still having issues getting this to work.

Basically, if the users IP is found in the text file I want the user to be redirected to `cnn.com`, if no IP then redirected to `google.com`

Here is the code that isn't working with my IP in the file:

```
<?php

$iplist = @file("ip.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$iparray = in_array($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"], $iplist);
//$iparray = in_array($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $iplist);

//###if ?test= is not empty
if (!empty($_GET["test"])){
        if($iparray){
            header("Location: http://cnn.com");die;
        }
}
header("Location: http://google.com");

?>
```

Note: I do have ?test=1 at the end of my URL when testing

I would like to keep the format of just keeping the if statement + stopping the rest of code from executing if possible so `header("Location: http://google.com");` does not execute.

Comment: Are you sure you have the ip in the file? (try `var_dump($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"], $iplist);` and check if the ip is really inside)

Comment: if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $iplist)) {
 header("Location: http://cnn.com");die;
} else {header("Location: http://google.com"); die()}

Comment: @DuaneLortie The quotes around `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` are completely unnecessary.

Comment: Verify that the `ip.txt` file is loading. Remove the `@` error suppression from the beginning of `file()` and see if any file warnings occur.

Comment: PS, I'm with Dekel. Possibly you have hidden chars in your IP text file. They can hide, but if you print it into a textarea tag, you may see gibberish chars that prevent them from matching

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois yup, I removed them.

Comment: Why not use a Database?

Comment: @Dekel positive its in the text file.. i have also tested with just my IP in the file with the same issue

Comment: @BoeNoe I cant use a database for this it has to be a test file

Comment: @JoeBobby Oh, ok.

Comment: @JoeBobby, what happen when you remove the `@` before the `file(...)` function?

Answer (score 0):

If your ip is in the file and the filepath is correct, try this:

```
if (false !== strpos(file_get_contents($filename), $ip_to_search)){
     // ip in the file
}
else {
     // otherwise
}
```

Comment: This will also give `true` for partial match (`1.2.3.1` will give true if the ip `101.2.3.101` exists on the file)

Comment: @Aleksey-Dubinin what would be the solution using the text file since I need the text file?

Comment: @Dekel, yeah, I thought about those circumstances. They are not very often but have to receive their attention, of course.

Comment: @JoeBobby, you can also use regexpressions, for example.
This also depends on how you store the ips.

One more thing: did you printed the $iplist array ?

Comment: @AlekseyDubinin the only thing in the text file are 1 IP per line, and spaces to separate IPs, and lines beginning with # to organize the IPs.. how do I print the $iplist?